# Display bootstrap datetimepicker as per in diffrent time zone

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, momentjs

I am trying display bootstrap datetimepicker with different time zone
referring [bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://github.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker/commit/d60867d192cdcdc92fbfa850397ec681de1dc2dd) but unable to achieve

I used below code from [Time zone setting](https://github.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker)

```
$('#date-end').datetimepicker({
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii P Z'
    timezone: 'GMT'
});
```

but its not working. can any one suggest me how can I display time according to different time zone.
How can I use `moment.js` to change time according to timezone?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#date-end').datetimepicker(options).on("changeDate", function (e) {
 var TimeZoned = new Date(e.date.setTime(e.date.getTime() + 
                            (e.date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)));
 $(this).datetimepicker('setDate', TimeZoned);
});
```

define bootstrap class and access this code in java script to different different time zone.